# How to store array values extracted using RegExp in jmeter into a file?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I have a script having RegExp fetched an **array of values** stored in a variable. I need to store values in a **file**. How it can be done using **bean shell post processor**.I have tried a code it stores only one value in a file. Please help me in this.

my request response is

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><GetCitiesByCountryResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET"><GetCitiesByCountryResult>&lt;NewDataSet&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;Country&gt;British Indian Ocean Territory&lt;/Country&gt;
    &lt;City&gt;Diego Garcia&lt;/City&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;Country&gt;India&lt;/Country&gt;
    &lt;City&gt;Ahmadabad&lt;/City&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;Country&gt;India&lt;/Country&gt;
    &lt;City&gt;Akola&lt;/City&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;Country&gt;India&lt;/Country&gt;
    &lt;City&gt;Aurangabad Chikalthan Aerodrome&lt;/City&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
  `
```

I want to store city names in a file using bean shell. How it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to work with the response of the [Global Weather](http://www.webservicex.net/New/Home/ServiceDetail/56) web service

If you need to save all the values of `<City>` nodes into a file I would recommend switching to [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and [Groovy language](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) as:

- [Groovy performance is much better than Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)
- [Groovy has built-in XML support](http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html)
- [Writing data into Files in Groovy is easy like a charm](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/working-with-io.html#_writing_files)

Example JSR223 PostProcessor Groovy code which will write each `<City>` found in the response into a file (each city on the new line) would look like:

```
def slurper = new XmlSlurper()

def xml = slurper.parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString())

def newDataSet = xml.'**'.find { node ->
    node.name() == 'GetCitiesByCountryResult'
}

def filteredResult = slurper.parseText(newDataSet.toString())

def cities = filteredResult.'**'.findAll { node ->
    node.name() == 'City'
}        

cities.each {
    new File('someFile.txt') << it << System.getProperty("line.separator")
}
```